# Selecting multiple elements with same values in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Input XML :

```
<Root>
    <NodeElement>
        <Element1>44</Element1>
        <Element2>472</Element2>            
        <Element3>A1.PDF</Element3> 
    </NodeElement>
    <NodeElement>
        <Element1>45</Element1>
        <Element2>472</Element2>            
        <Element3>A1.PDF</Element3> 
    </NodeElement>
    <NodeElement>
        <Element1>1318</Element1>
        <Element2>345</Element2>            
        <Element3>B1.PDF</Element3> 
    </NodeElement>
    <NodeElement>
        <Element1>1319</Element1>
        <Element2>345</Element2>            
        <Element3>C1.PDF</Element3> 
    </NodeElement>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</Root>
```

Output Required :

```
<Docs>
    <Doc>
        <Name> A1.PDF</Name>
        <Units>
            <Unit>
                <Element1>44</Element1>
                <Element2>472</Element2>  
            </Unit>
            <Unit>
                <Element1>45</Element1>
                <Element2>472</Element2> 
            </Unit>         
        </Units>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Name> B1.PDF</Name>
        <Units>
            <Unit>          
                <Element1>1318</Element1>
                <Element2>345</Element2>            
            </Unit>         
        </Units>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Name> C1.PDF</Name>
        <Units>
            <Unit>          
                <Element1>1319</Element1>
                <Element2>345</Element2>            
            </Unit>         
        </Units>
    </Doc>
        ..
        ..
        ..
</Docs>
```

I need to Merge the elements if I found elements having same values. Like above, I need to create Doc element and add elements with values to it. 
I need help, how this can be achieved with xslt.

Comment: (1) [mcve] would be appreciated. (2) Grouping depends on your XSLT Version; XSLT 1.0 you might have to go with [Muenchian](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html); XSLT 2.0 Function `xsl:for-each-group`. (3) If you follow 1 & state your XSLT version, you might get a solution within hours. BUT you have to describe via [edit] how to generate your output.

Answer (score 0):

Muenchian methodology that is using xsl:key function solved my problem.